Can I track an event server side on Google Analytics 4 only using user_id (and NOT client_id)?
Let's assume this flow:

User logins to the app
A user-id is set to a unique hash my-unique-user-id on google analytics client SDK.
Then, on server side, I want to track a My Custom Event that applies to logged-in users.
Because I'm able to generate the same user-id again, my-unique-user-id I want to ommit the client_id by doing that:

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    // client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY'
    user_id: 'my-unique-user-id'
    events: [{
      name: 'My Custom Event',
      params: {},
    }]
  })
});

I want to avoid retrieving the client_id from the frontend, because I know the user-id, and it should be able to reconciliate, right ?
Can I ommit the client_id in case of user_id being set ?
Thanks.
